# Error Compile poco-lib 1.12.5 with make and arm cross-compiler arm-linux-g++

Tags: poco, poco-libraries

I cant compile poco-lib for my embedded device with arm-linux-g++ compiler.

i assume that the cross compiler only supports cxx11, but poco has to be compiled with cxx17 ?

i tryed with a older version. it works with 1.9.0 Version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/189b7b0911031aef56f3e0da7615d56ce41eaa62/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L47-L52), [it works](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/actions/runs/7769189745/job/21187984760#step:4:1) and will be released in the upcoming 1.13.1 release